# MongoDB select data which is not older than a week

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I'm trying to select data that is not older then I week, I need something like this from mysql:

`WHERE date <= one week ago`

Here is my current query:

```
$this->aggregate(
                array(
                    array('$sort' => array( '_id' => self::SORT_DESC)),
                    array('$match' => array( 'seen' => 0)),
                    array('$group' => array('_id'=>'$target_user',
                        'type' => array('$push'=> array('type' => '$type',
                            'title'=>'$title',
                            'link'=>'$link',
                            'dt'=>'$dt',
                            'own'=>'$own',
                            'usr'=>'$usr'))
                        )),
                    ));
```

The field `dt` in `$group` is a string date which is stored like this: `2013-10-14 14:53:11` so based on the `dt` key I need data the isn't older than a week.

Can something like this be done in Mongo?

Comment: `, 'date' => array('$lte'=>strtotime('-1 week',$date_field))`

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? mabe post a full answer, thank you

Comment: Within your php model what is the name of the variable that holds your date? Also is it string or is it MongoDate?

Comment: I don't have any variable that holds the date, and yes it is a string, the date is only stored in the DB, the key in which the date is stored is ` dt` as you can see in the ` $group`

Comment: hmm I would consider storing it as a string a really bad idea, currently mongodb can only manipulate actual date objects in aggregation, it cannotn cast strings to dates like SQL techs can yet

Comment: So If I insert a unixtime as a string will it work?

Comment: I don't believe so, or it will be very difficult, you want to insert using MongoDBs own date object, i.e. ISODate or in PHP MongoDate, you will also want a time to start from

Comment: I have updated the database to use MongoDate, but now I don't know how to query it, to query data that is NOT older than a week, I tried: `                    array('$sort' => array( 'dt' => array('$gt' => new \MongoDate(strtotime('10/1/2013'))))),` but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MongoDate you can do:

```
$this->aggregate(
    array(
       array('$match' => array( 'seen' => 0, 'dt' => array('$gte'=> new \MongoDate(strtotime('-1 week'))))),
       array('$sort' => array( '_id' => self::SORT_DESC)),
       array('$group' => array('_id' => '$target_user',
          'type' => array('$push'=> array('type' => '$type',
              'title'=>'$title',
              'link'=>'$link',
              'dt'=>'$dt',
              'own'=>'$own',
              'usr'=>'$usr'))
    )),
 ));
```